# Android audio recording using phone microphone when handsfree is attached

Tags: android, audio-recording, microphone

When I connect bluetooth handsfree to Android phone device, is it possible to use phone microphone to record sound and hear it in the handsfree?

I manage to record sound by phone microphone and hear it on the phone speaker or headphones. But when the headphones has microphone, typically handsfree, it records sound using handsfree microphone by default. I need to mute somehow handsfree microphone and use phone microphone. Is it possible in Android?

I haven't found any answer. At android developers, Stackoverflow, nowhere. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use the MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER to record the audio.

according to the api-doc it is

> *Microphone audio source with same orientation as camera if available, the main device microphone otherwise*

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. No sound come from the microphone.