# How to set recording source to device microphone when a handsfree is connected?

Tags: android, audiorecord

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578972/android-audio-recording-using-phone-microphone-when-handsfree-is-attached) i use `AudioRecord` to record from internal device Mic as follows:

```
            recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, sRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N);
```

I need to record from **internal mic** when headset is connected(and not headset's Mic).
Can `setParameters()`, `setRouting()`, `setMode()` methods of `AudioRecord` be helpful?